# What is the method to convert a JArray contained within a JArray to a string?

Tags: c#, json

I use newton's json of C#.
Before I start, I know a bit about the json form, but I'm not sure I know it perfectly.
Therefore, the corresponding json form may be an incorrect json form.\

This is json's sample data.

```
{ "data" :
  [
    [
      {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"value2"
      },{
        "key1":"value3",
        "key2":"value4"
      }
    ],[
      {
        "key10":"value10"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

This json data is the current JObject Type.
I would like to receive this JObject in the following string form.

```
    [
      {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"value2"
      },{
        "key1":"value3",
        "key2":"value4"
      }
    ],[
      {
        "key10":"value10"
      }
    ]
```

I tried this code.

```
    //JObject jobj = /*Sample json*/;
    string json = (jobj["data"] as JArray)[0].ToString();
```

This code returns the following results.

```
    [
      {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"value2"
      },{
        "key1":"value3",
        "key2":"value4"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: What do you want is not valid json, you have to learn that each json should have a root before asking the question.

Comment: @Serge To be fair, OP never said what they wanted *is* valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want is not a valid json, it is just a string

```
    json =  JObject.Parse(json)["data"].ToString();
    string str = json.Substring(1,json.Length-2);
```

Comment: I understood that it is acceptable to forcibly substring from the string since it is not in JSON format. This solution seems fine to me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your desired result is not valid JSON. It is two JSON arrays, separated by a comma. There is no single "root" element.

So to produce your desired output, just join the arrays' string representations with commas. [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-7.0#system-string-join-1(system-string-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))) does exactly that.

```
if (jobj["data"]?.Values<JArray>() is IEnumerable<JArray?> arrays)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", arrays));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  
However, I can't test it because it's not C# 8.0 version or higher. For other people, this may work correctly.

Comment: @HRP It's just a null check to check if `data` is actually a 2D array. You can also just do `var arrays = jobj["data"]?.Values<JArray>();` and then `if (array != null) { ... }`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json.Linq to Deserialize the input string into a JToken as below.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(res);
```

And retrieve the "data" list as below.

```
var _data = (JArray)result["data"];
```

OR

```
var _data = result["data"].ToList();
```

If you want to convert it to a string, you can use .ToString() as below

```
string _data = result["data"].ToString();
```

Comment: This is no better than the question's code. In fact, it does even less. The question shows that the string is already parsed using JSON.NET into `jobs` and converts the first array element to text with `(jobj["data"] as JArray)[0].ToString();`